# How to group results to boolean value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which returns

```
Select bool_val
from .....
```

The query returns many rows with values of `True` or `False` or no rows at all.

I want the query to ALWAYS return `True` Or `False` based on condition that if there is one true the result is `True` otherwise `False`.

For example:
query result:

```
False
False
True
False
```

Should return `True`.

query result:

```
False
False
```

Should return `False`.

query result:

```
no rows
```

Should return `False` since the query is empty.

How can I do that with a query without `IFs` using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a boolean aggregate:

```
select bool_or(bool_val)
from the_table;
```

To also get a `false` when the table contains no rows, use `coalesce()` (thanks Elad)

```
select coalesce(bool_or(bool_val), false)
from the_table;
```

Another - possibly faster - option is:

```
select exists (select 1 from the_table where bool_val)
```

Comment: It's also possible to avoid the union if using `select coalesce(bool_or(bool_val),False) from the_table...;` The `coalesce` will handle the case of no rows returned.